# Riak CS: Stanchion failover

Tags: riak-cs

From the Riak CS docs, I understand that only one Stanchion server should be used for a cluster. In my cluster I'm spinning up identical machines that all have the same setup, so that theoretically any machine could takeover if needed.

Ideally I would like to have Stanchion also running on all servers and if the main Stanchion server fails, I want another server to take over that role. Can this work or do I need to isolate the Stanchion server on to a separate machine (with a failover machine)? Or can I configure a list of IPs for the Stanchion server, so that if the main one becomes unavailable automatically the next one is tried?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm working understanding / setting up the same behaviour right now with an HAProxy

Comment: I switched to a different system in the end, so no I never really resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to isolate Stanchion in separate box. At the latest version of CS has `riak-cs-stanchion` command to switch Stanchion host and port to new ones manually. Please make sure that former Stanchion is down before running this command to all CS nodes. Well, sooo a late answer.

http://docs.basho.com/riakcs/latest/cookbooks/command-line-tools/#riak-cs-stanchion